# Get SVG from http GET method and display it

Tags: html, angular, svg

I'm trying to display a SVG image in my webapp but I don't own the SVG as a file "image.svg", I call my service and it responds with a http response. The response is as below :

```
"headers": {
        "access-control-allow-methods": [
            "PUT"
        ],
        "content-length": [
            "249664"
        ],
        "x-powered-by": [
            "Express"
        ],
        "content-disposition": [
            "attachment; filename=out.svg"
        ],
        "etag": [
            "W/\"3cf40-pgVjFGaVCiK8oIvC+f36ew7CrB8\""
        ],
        "access-control-allow-headers": [
            "Content-Type, Authorisation"
        ],
        "connection": [
            "keep-alive"
        ],
        "access-control-allow-origin": [
            "*"
        ],
        "date": [
            "Fri, 22 Nov 2019 14:06:47 GMT"
        ],
        "content-type": [
            "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        ]
    },
    "body": "PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3 [...] 5lPjwvc3ZnPg=="
```

I already try to use an object tag with the [data] attribute and passing the content of the body in that [data] field, but the result is not as excepted (it's my webapp but in a litle window... I don't understand)

Is there a way to display that SVG without downloading it as a file ?

Comment: why can't you just use an img tag with the src set?

Comment: please post complete body of response. Is the body is base64 encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DomSanitizer` for sanitizing your `base64` image. Import `DomSanitizer` and use in `HTML` as follows,

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  // variable containing image string (base64)
  // in your case body of response
  svgData = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { } // inject domsanitizer
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<img [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/svg+xml;base64, '+ svgData)">
```

Demo [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nzkawl)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried it but it doen't work, it gives me the "broken-picture" logo and no errors, when analyzing the img with "inspect element" tool, everything is like yours but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it works now, I forgot to remove an NgIf* and now it's working thanks !